# Xamarin forms white-labeled app (multi branded)

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.forms, white-labelling

I am building an Xamarin Forms IOS, Android and UWP app that can be custom branded for different clients (e.g. white-labeled). Their apps are exactly the same except for Info.plist, bundle identifier, name, app icons, assets and a few other minor things.

Personally, I thought of a project with multiple build configurations. (pre-build event scripts)

Does anyone know how I can realize this step by step(try it out)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i see it, You could have a main set of projects (shared, platfrom-dependent, controls etc) with a skin system implemented - this is your app with all the functionality, let's call it "A".

Then You would have different VS solutions for each brand with projects "A" + "B - the launcher shared project for a specific brand, with appropriate bundle id etc".

Comment: I think it is useful to have one project, namely because about 90% of the code are the same. It is unnecessary to create a new solution for each brand

Comment: You will not copy your 90% code, you will be including same code to different solutions. :)

Comment: One solution could become massive though, right? With multiple build configurations relying on the same projects?

Comment: Not really. In addition you can compact some your shared code into private nuget packages to include in your projects, to make the solution even smaller.